# JQuery AJAX and autopopulate dropdown menu

Tags: json, jquery

so I can't seem to get my dropdown menu to work.  Here's the code:

```
$.ajax({
url:"/json/testjson",
cache:true,
success: function(j){
console.log(j);
alert(j);}
});
```

This returns a valid json string:

```
{"data": ["test", "data"], "result": "OK"}
```

I can't get the success function to fire at all.  There is no error anywhere (neither in the firebug log, nor in the netlog, and the response from the site is okay. The firebug parser cannot parse that JSON but the JLINT validator validates it correctly. I have tried the setting the content-type to application/json, no success. I have also tried, $.getJSON, $.get, and nothing is firing.  I have also tried

Any ideas?

Thanks
Jon

Comment: did you try error:function(responseText, status){ alert (responseText) } this will help you to see what is wrong. By the way is your method returning JSON or sting. if it is returning JSON stirng then you will have to parse the stirng to JSON.

Comment: I stripped that all out so that I can see what happens when I call it.  I also added the error function and it is not called.

Comment: remove your cache:true and check it. also try JSON.parse(j)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you HaBo - the answer was to remove the cache: true!

Thanks!
J

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to set `dataType` to `json` to make sure the data coming from the server is treated as a `json` object.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/json/testjson",
    dataType: "json",
    cache: true,
    success: function(j) {
        console.log(j);
        alert(j);
    }
});
```

Take a look at the [$.ajax API](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).